# Why does this query return nil from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the three most recent documents from my collection group `userPosts` using the following database structure and query:

```
-posts
   -{userID}
      -userPosts
         -{documentID}
            -postTime(Field)
```

Query:

```
postQuery = Firestore.firestore()
            .collectionGroup("userPosts")
            .order(by: "postTime", descending: true)
            .limit(to: 3)
```

function used to query Firestore:

```
func loadPosts() {
    postQuery.getDocuments{ [weak self](querySnapshot, error) in
        self!.q.async{
            var postsTemp = self?.postArray
            for doc in querySnapshot!.documents{
                self?.documents += [doc]
                let post = self!.createPost(doc)
                if(!self!.postArray.contains(post)){
                    postsTemp?.insert(post, at: 0)
                }
                 
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self!.postArray = postsTemp!
                    self!.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run this I get an error due to the fact that `querySnapshot` is nil. I am not sure why this happens since when I change descending to false I get a result but in the opposite order that I want. I have a feeling it has something to do with my query but am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: AFIK, with the collectionGroup the orderby may need `Indexing`, have you got any error saying to create index?

Comment: No, I have already created my index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDocuments` callback gets called with two values (`querySnapshot` and `error), **only one of which will have a value**.

You're ignoring the `error` and assuming that `querySnapshot` has a value, which not only leads to the error you get, but also hides the likely cause.

I recommend following the pattern used in this example from the Firestore documentation on [getting documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift_4):

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
}
```

By logging the `error` you can see what went wrong with your `getDocuments()` call.